# How to compare two strings with unicode have some diffrent?

Tags: c#

Things happened so confused.
I use these

```
(cert.SubjectName.Name.ToLower()) == (subjectName.ToLower()
```

to compare tow strings.
While I always get false even I can see these to strings have same value.
Then I figure out that, if I open the value in text visualizar, an select show Unicode control characters
I found the second value has |* at the beginning.
[image]

Why these happened?
How should I make these two string return true to me?

Comment: Instead of tweaking the comparison, you should find out why `cert.SubjectName.Name` has a strange character at the beginning.

Comment: Looks like it might be some sort of nonprintable character, such as a line feed or form feed. What is its Unicode code point?

Comment: HI cert.SubjectName.Name return right value, it's subjectName. I get these value in web.config file: WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Common.SigningCertificateName]
I use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Common.SigningCertificateName] with no lucky

Comment: And |*C is one character

Answer (score 0):

Probably your app.config contains the weird character, which you may not be able to see in your regular editor:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="SigningCertificateName" value="<WEIRD-CHAR>CN=STSTestCert" />
</appSettings>
```

Try deleting the whole value (`"CN=STSTestCert"`), and re-typing it.